# How to securely connect to an SQL server using Python3

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I need to connect to a remote Microsoft SQL database using python and my connection call contains the username & password of the database. I really don't want to send this info as a raw text on the internet. Is there a way I can encrypt (secure) the connection between the SQL server and the python3 code, and what library is better used for that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can connect to DB Instance

```
import pyodbc

server = 'YOUR_DB_HOST_NAME' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
conn= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

And about secure connection issue, you can refer [Using Always Encrypted with the ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=An%20Always%20Encrypted%20enabled%20driver,data%20in%20the%20client%20application.) from Microsoft.